# （wordpress）Plugin Error:You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: wordpress

My plugin which adds a menu in admin page has two files.

The code of the main file (`special.php`) is as follows:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_add_pages');
function my_add_pages() {
  add_menu_page('special', 'special', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'specialPage');
}
function specialPage() {
  ....
}
```

In the function `specialPage()`, I write a link:

```
<a href="admin.php?page=special/special_edit.php?do=edit&id=<?php echo $spec->spec_id;?>">Edit<a>
```

I write this link because i want to go to another file `special_edit.php`. The file is in the same folder (`plugin/special`) as `special.php`.

However when i click the "Edit" link, it reminds me that "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page".

Where does the problem come from? How can I solve it?

Comment: There is a stackexchange site specialized on WordPress questions, now... You can get a better audience there. I can't move it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
admin.php?page=special/special_edit.php?do=edit&id=...
```

I think you must replace the second ? with a &
And probably drop the .php extension of the page parameter (just guessing, here, I haven't hacked WordPress much).

[UPDATE] I checked, and it seems that with add_menu_page, you should use an identifier like `'special_edit'` in the menu slug, instead of `__FILE__`. Would look nicer anyway, and will be independent of your file names.

Comment: I have tried . I change it to "add_menu_page('special', 'special', 'manage_options',special, 'specialPage'); " And if "<*a href="?page=special/special_edit&id=<?php echo $spec->spec_id;?>">Edit</*a>" should be changed?

Comment: I tried to change the href to special.php?id=<?php echo $spec->spec_id;?> It reminded me "Not Found"

Comment: I think it should be: `add_menu_page('special', 'special', 'manage_options', 'special_edit', 'specialPage');` (with quotes) and link should be `<a href=admin.php?page=special_edit&id=<?php echo $spec->spec_id;?>">Edit</a>` Note: use backquotes to escape code.

Comment: It just skip to the current page ,but I want the link go to the page of special_edit.php,and current page is special.php.the two files are in the same folder.

Comment: The examples I see (plugins I have) just call a function inside the same .php file, so I don't know if cross-file calls are possible. You should look at WordPress Codex.

Comment: Actually, i am facing same problem and trying to do exactly what you were.So my question is how did you solve it

Answer (score -1):

Edit table **wp_usermeta** and change value of **wp_capabilities** to:

```
a:1:{s:13:”administrator”;b:1;}
```

Comment: Before I changed the value of wp_capabilities,the main file of my plugin can be accessed. However,after I changed,the main file of my plugin can't be access ,else!